# How Namenode High availability achieved in Hadoop 1.x?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

Is there any possible solution to achieve Namenode HA in Hadoop 1.x ?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 1.x is known for its single point of failure; there is a single Master Node that contains Hadoop Namenode and Hadoop JobTracker. The Namenode keeps look up table for every file (blocks of the file) location on the cluster. The Name node manages Hadoop Distributed File system and act as a HDFS master.

The Secondary NameNode is used for fault tolerance and it is a copy of the NameNode records. It is only used to backup the Namenode in case of crash.

Comment: Does it require any downtime of the cluster for shifting to secondary if NameNode crashed?

Comment: yes indeed, all the cluster jobs will be killed and run again.